# Are quaternions used in tensor analysis?

Tags: tensors, quaternions

At the moment I am learning tensor analysis. In the books I study (civil engineering/mechanical books on tensors) there is a lot written about rotation matrices/tensors, however quaternions are not even mentioned. I know that for example in computer games quaternions are used extensively for this purpose, and they have some significant advantages over rotation matrices. Are there any formal problems that make people avoid quaternions? Do you know any tutorials/books in which (for example mechanical) problems are expressed using quaternions, not rotation matrices?

Comment: Quaternions aren't tensors.  Quaternions are *spinors* (which are objects which satisfy different transformation rules than tensors).  You can certainly use both spinors and tensors in the same problem, but I'm guessing most books on tensor analysis aren't going to cover spinors because they're just different objects.

Comment: @gotit--thanks You wrote that one can use both spinors and tensors in the same problem. Is that always valid? Can I describe for example tension using quaternions (or other spinors?) instead of tensors?

Comment: Just because you can use both together doesn't mean that you can interchange both of them.  There might be a way of describing tension by a spinor, but I think it's probably better described by a vector (in the case of a rope) or the Cauchy stress tensor.  An example of using both in the same problem would be describing the position of the Earth by a vector (a type of tensor) and describing its rotation around the Sun via a time dependent quaternion (a type of spinor).

Comment: Spinors are naturally part of an algebra called geometric (Clifford) algebra.  For a good reference try [*Geometric Algebra for Physicists* by Chris Doran and Anthony Lasenby](http://www.amazon.com/Geometric-Algebra-Physicists-Chris-Doran/dp/0521715954).